# Tengo un problema para mostrar datos de una key vacía en un dataframe con pandas en Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Estoy tratando de asignar a una nueva columna de mi DF el valor que se encuentra alojado en la key "TYPE_OF_DOCUMENT" dentro del array de "INDIVIDUAL_DOCUMENT". Probé con muchas validaciones, pero en los casos que la llave se encuentra vacía, como en el caso a continuación, no logro que el programa me lo reemplace por "X". Sino que me lo deja como un dato vacío en el df.

En los casos que la key "TYPE_OF_DOCUMENT" simplemente no existe, si me hace el reemplazo por "X". Pero no funciona en los casos vacíos como este:

```
"INDIVIDUAL_DOCUMENT":[{"TYPE_OF_DOCUMENT":"","TYPE_OF_DOCUMENT2":""}]
```

```
df["DOC.TIPO"] = df['INDIVIDUAL_DOCUMENT'].apply(lambda x: x[0].get('TYPE_OF_DOCUMENT', "X") if len(x) != 0 and any(x) and isinstance(x[0], dict) and 'TYPE_OF_DOCUMENT' in x[0] else "X")
```

Comment: Por el código que pruebas parece que estás usando pandas, pero no hay ejemplo de cómo es el dataframe, pues el ejemplo de datos que pones justo antes  no se entiende ¿es un diccionario cuyo valor es una lista de diccionarios? ¿Necesitas realmente hacerlo vía pandas o es la idea que se te ha ocurrido? A lo mejor es más sencillo procesar directamente los datos de entrada según cómo te lleguen éstos. ¿Quizás un json?

Comment: Buen día, las preguntas que buscan ayuda con la depuración deben incluir el comportamiento esperado, un problema específico o error, y el código más corto necesario para reproducirlo en la propia pregunta. Las preguntas sin un planteamiento claro del problema no son útiles para otros lectores. Véase: Cómo crear un [Ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

Vale, en este caso no se esta sustituyendo el valor '' por 'X' porque la llave si existe en el diccionario de referencia y explicitamente indica que regresa el valor de ''.

`"TYPE_OF_DOCUMENT":""` --> `''` porque existe en el diccionario

`"TYPE_OF_DOCUMENT3":""` --> `'X'` porque no existe en el diccionario

Dado el ejemplo, me parece que esto seria lo equivalente buscado:

```
dc_ref = {
    "TYPE_OF_DOCUMENT": "",
    "TYPE_OF_DOCUMENT1": "Y",
    "TYPE_OF_DOCUMENT2": "Z"
    }

df = pd.DataFrame(
data = [
        "TYPE_OF_DOCUMENT",
        "TYPE_OF_DOCUMENT1",
        "TYPE_OF_DOCUMENT2",
        "TYPE_OF_DOCUMENT3"
        ],
columns = ["INDIVIDUAL_DOCUMENT"]
)

df.loc[:,"DOC_TIPO"] = df['INDIVIDUAL_DOCUMENT'].apply(
    lambda x: 
        dc_ref.get(x, "XX") # Valor del diccionario, si no existe, regresa 'XX'
        if dc_ref.get(x, "X") # != '' En caso que el valor del diccionario sea ''
        else 'X' # Regresa el Valor de 'X'
    )
```

Espero que sea de ayuda.